# xslt transformation move data to child element

Tags: xslt

I have a source file o with the following data

```
#POST_START                     
#ID 2           
#NAME John Doe                                     
#STREET Big Street 1                     
#ZIP 1111111                     
#CITY LONDON      
#POST_END               
#POST_START
#ID 3           
#NAME Jonathan Swift                                     
#STREET Little Street 9                     
#ZIP 333333
#CITY PARIS 
POST_END
```

I need to transform this to the following structure

```
<persons>
    <person>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>John Doe</name>
    <address>
        <street>Big Street</street>
        <zip>111111</zip>
        <city>LONDON</city>
    </address>
    </person>
    <person>
    <id>3</id>
    <name>Jonathan Swift</name>
    <address>
        <street>Little Street</street>
        <zip>333333</zip>
        <city>PARIS</city>
    </address>
    </person>
</persons>
```

What is the best way to achive this? I´ve tried and managed to get most part right, but i don´t seem to be able to insert the address element and "push down" the street, zip and city to a child level.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You'll have to show us your XSLT to get better help in identifying where you run into problems. Also, XSLT doesn't seem like a good fit for your requirements. It works by transforming input XML documents. Trying to create XML from a source file that is not appears backwards and is better handled in some other way.

Comment: "*I´ve tried and managed to get most part right*" Post your attempt so we can fix it and don't have to start from scratch (plus I would *really* like to see how you managed to process a text file with XSLT...).